# Why is my rubgems not making symbolic links to binaries?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 with ruby 1.9.2p180 installed from source using rvm. When I install a gem that makes a command-line binary, links are not made. For example, when I install the passenger gem, `/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/bin/passenger` is installed as expected and works, but a symbolic link is not made from `/usr/bin/passenger` as expected.

**update**

actually I have the same problem with vendor ruby and gem (on a different 11.04 server that has never had rvm).

```
$ sudo gem install bundler
$ bundle
bash: bundle: command not found
$ type bundle
-bash: type: bundle: not found
$ ls -lF /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 383 2011-08-13 19:49 /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/bundle*
```

Comment: Have you considered adding `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/` to your `PATH` manually? There is some controversy going on about this issue, for example: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby1.9.1/+bug/706603

Comment: Yep, that's one solution -- but on my experience in other systems, gem will always make a symlink or a copy from /usr/bin to the gem executable... (i think?).

Answer (score 8):

RVM installation should be self-contained, which means it won't create symlinks out of the RVM directory. That should not be problem, though, as passenger binary should be added to path automatically by RVM.

Basically it should work like this:

```
$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290
$ which gem

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem

$ gem install passenger
$ which passenger

~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/passenger
```

I would guess that you are using ubuntu's version of gem and ruby. `rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 --default` should fix that.

If rvm function is not accessible, add this to your .bash_profile:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

See https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ for details.

Comment: actually i have the same problem with vendor ruby/gem -- i've updated my question

Answer (score 5):

I guess this can be your problem: installing rvm gems with `sudo`. Given you have the right privileges in your machine, this is not needed. But if you really need this, do `rvmsudo gem install bundler` instead.